# When I select radio button my app crashed

Tags: android, arraylist, radio-button, indexoutofboundsexception

I have 3 Radio buttons each radio buttons to do some performs, Using this Radio Buttons I am filtering  my Results E.g for RB1 for DATE-WISE RB2 for customernames and RB3 for Productname.

Above two radio buttons working good(RB2 and RB3), but when I choose RB3(DATE-WISE) my Application Crashed.

```
final RadioGroup rgroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioType);
        final RadioButton Ta = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.type_a);
        final RadioButton Tb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.type_b);
        final RadioButton Tc = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.type_c);
        rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()     {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == Ta.getId()) {
                    cus_names = listItems.get(cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition());
                    btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    created_date1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    created_date2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cus_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    po_id.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else if (rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == Tb.getId()) {
                    cus_name.setSelection(0);
                    cus_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    created_date1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    created_date2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    po_id.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else if (rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == Tc.getId()) {
                    po_id.setSelection(0);
                    po_id.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    created_date1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    created_date2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cus_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

My Logcat:

```
07-28 11:47:53.243 13244-13244/com.example.Minal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.Minal, PID: 13244
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
    at com.example.Minal.Purchase_Pending$1.onCheckedChanged(Purchase_Pending.java:180)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.-wrap0(RadioGroup.java)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:351)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:159)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:115)
    at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: `cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition()` has returned negative 1 and your list is empty. Two problems there

Comment: cus_names = listItems.get(cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition()); check your listItems size

Comment: yes my list is empty you Right @cricket_007,because i have no data in my database. How to handle this type of situation?

Comment: my list size is empty @Pravin

Comment: Insert data in the database? Check the length of the list before you try to access any element in it?

Comment: thats why you're getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception

Comment: Please [edit] to show a [mcve] you say database, but your question doesn't show it. You also have the list items variable that isn't defined

Comment: yes @cricket_007 i already checked when database have data means working good,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written below line at wrong position, so whenever you will get empty list it will crash your app,

```
cus_names = listItems.get(cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

So try below code for all three condition not in onle,

```
if(listItmes != null & listItems.size() > 0)
      cus_names = listItems.get(cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; **index=-1** his cus_name has no selection so having data or not won't change anything

Answer (score 2):

In your case the reason is `cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition()` return -1 (it is not a index of your listItem) and your listItem size is 0.
So you should check both of it before get value for prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` like

```
if(cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition() > -1 && cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition() < listItems.size()){
      cus_names = listItems.get(cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition());
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Can I check >0 or -1 which one is right? I think -1 is better right?

Comment: I have some case for you.

`your list have 0 item and  cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition() = -1 (false)  
- your list have 0 item and  cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition() = 1 (false)  
- your list have 1 item and  cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition() = -1(false)  
- your list have 1 item and  cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition() = 1(false)  
your list have 1 item and  cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition() = 0(true)`

Comment: so i am going to use -1\

Comment: @AndroidBoy test this case `your list have 1 item and cus_name.getSelectedItemPosition() = -1` if using my code or the accept answer. i'm sure you will know the idea